# Why my Position to Position mapping using Mix Mode doesn't work as expected Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I just want to know the reason behind this Geometry Node setup attached as it is not working.Kindly note that both have same number of vertices.
I just want cube points to go to sphere points in any order.I don't care about shape. But when i make mix factor 1, cube just scales down. What might be the reason behind this?
[image]

Comment: you have to use the sample (index) node to get values from one gn branch to another. The capture attribute works only on the same branch